# Regarding Haskell's Parametricity concept

Tags: haskell

This is a question from book "Haskell Programming from First Principles".

I am reading the above mentioned book, On chapter 5, Number 2 of Exercises: Parametricity.

Copied from the book.

**We can get a more comfortable appreciation of parametricity
by looking at a -> a -> a. This hypothetical
function a -> a -> a has two–and only two–implementations.**

I do not understand "only two–implementations" part? can any one explain to me why only 2 implementations?

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain formally, but just try to think up ways you could implement a function that, given two elements of the same type, produces a single one of that type - *for every conceivable type*. The two possible implementations are rather obvious, and (speaking informally) there is "nothing else you can do" because you can't assume *anything* about the values the function takes, as you don't know anything about their type.

Comment: ```\nf x y = x
    f x y = y
    f x y = x + y\n```,so i have defined 3 functions

Comment: the last one doesn't have type `a -> a -> a` but `Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Comment: Suppose I give you two boxes, and I tell you that the things in these boxes are the same type of thing, but I *don’t* tell you what they are. Now I ask you to give me back something of that same type, deterministically (no using `IO` to flip a coin) and “honestly” (no breaking open a box to see what’s inside, no lying to me about what you gave me, no running away with the boxes and never returning). Since you know nothing about what’s in the boxes, you can’t just *make* something of that type—you *must* give me back one of the boxes I gave you, and you only have two possible choices.

Comment: @JonPurdy, that explanation is pretty good, thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the word "implementations" can be a bit confusing at first glance.

Say we have *only* the function type `f :: a -> a -> a`, and no other information; we're not allowed to peek inside `f`. The function must return an `a` and you only have 2 possible `a`'s as input. Therefore the function must return the first `a` **or** the second `a`; only 2 possible functions.

You cannot have `f x y = x + y` because you do not know how to `+` two `a`'s just given that `f :: a -> a -> a`. If you have, say `h :: Int -> Int -> Int`, then `h x y = x + y` would be a valid function, but you are not given that information for `f`.

Similarly, what if you have `f :: a -> a -> a` and you claim `f x y = x + y` **is valid**. Then I can break your claim by passing two `Fruit`s to `f`: `f Apple Orange = ???`. Well `Apple + Orange` is ambiguous and the code wont work. So keeping the type polymorphic "restricts" the possible functions to 2 possible "implementations": `f x y = x` or `f x y = y`.

This [video](https://youtu.be/ngswgTy7Ao8?t=1888) helped me understand. I'd recommend the whole video but the link is to the relevant part. (31:28)

It demonstrates the power of type-level reasoning and parametricity. All the information for such reasoning is in the type.

Another example, say all you have is a function type `g :: b -> b`. Well, the function must return a `b`, and the only argument is a `b` so it must return *that* `b`. Thus, there is only **one** such function with type `b -> b`.

Comment: it's three. the third one returns `undefined`: `f a b = undefined`. there's even more definitions, `f a b = f a b` and `f a b = f b a`, and even `f a b = f (f a b) (f b a)`, but they all "return" `undefined`.

Comment: @Will, any function of any signature whatsoever could return `undefined`. And it could do that without inspecting its arguments/parameters at all. So it doesn't count as parametric. Your infinite recursion examples don't return at all, so they don't count either. @DavOS: good answer!

Comment: @AntC yes, that's what I meant by "they all 'return' `undefined`" (error and looping both considered as *bottom*). so discounting *that kind of "solutions"*, it is indeed two. but we do need to discount them.

Comment: Parametricity is a property of *total* functions; something that "returns" `undefined` is a so-called partial function. (The term "total function" is something of a retronym; historically, a function by definition mapped each value of its domain to a value in its co-domain. A partial function isn't a function at all in that sense.)

Comment: There is parametricity for partial functions, it's just a bit more complicated, but you can still derive laws from types.  However I think everybody uses the total laws in practice; in practical Haskell, it's very nice to pretend that everything is total most of the time, and leave bottoms as a escape hatch if things get very subtle. But total, so called "fast and loose", reasoning works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

There are five functions (up to observational equivalence in the pure expression (non-IO) part of Haskell) which have the most general type `a -> a -> a`.

```
f0 a b = f0 (f0 b a) (f0 a b) 

f1 a b = if True then a else b

f2 = flip f1

f3 a b = seq a (f2 a b)

f4 = flip f3
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).