# Non-exhaustive patterns in function when using an example from a haskell book

Tags: haskell

I tried to run this code:

```
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
product [] = 1


sum [] = 0
sum (n:ns) = n + sum ns

sum [2,3,6]


product [2,3,4]
```

and for some reason it is giving me the "Non-exhaustive patterns in function" error, for both `sum` and `product` definitions.

Why are those patterns non-exhaustive? I've defined the functions on an empty list and of a list of 1 or more elements. What more does it need?

I am using `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.4` and these examples are from the book by Graham Hutton. Has something changed in the Haskell compiler since 2016 (when the book was written).

Comment: Are you entering this code in GHCi one line at a time? If so, don't -- each line will redefine the previously defined function. Write your definitions in a .hs file and load that in GHCi instead, after which you can test your functions.

Comment: Always write a type signature, `product :: [Int] -> Int` or more general `product :: Num a => [a] -> a`.

Comment: @Iceland_jack why is it better to wirte it than to omit it?

Comment: @pavel_orekhov It is a good idea to write the type because it helps finding bugs early. Indeed, sometimes a bug causes Haskell to silently infer an unintended type. If you write a type, Haskell will complain immediately about the inferred type not matching the provided one. If you don't, the unintended type is taken, and you probably will get type errors later on. It's painful to debug code when the error points to a line where there's nothing wrong, and the actual issue is elsewhere. Consider, e.g., what kinds of errors could be caused much later on by the mistake `first (x, y) = y`.

Comment: Type signatures are the primary means of communicating intention in Haskell, to the compiler, to other programmers and as a sanity check for yourself. Sometimes an incorrect program compiles but with an incorrect type signature. It also helps you, the programmer, to think about the signature of a function before you start writing the definition. For some definitions like `id` and `($) = id` the type signature is the only thing the distinguishes them, they have the same definition but the types `a -> a` and `(a -> b) -> a -> b` indicate different intention.

Comment: [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Ord%20a%20%3D%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) is a search engine for types. "[Parametricity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452440/regarding-haskells-parametricity-concept)" says that types of polymorphic functions tells you a lot of properties about their implementation. The type `[a] -> [a]` (like `reverse`) tells me that the function cannot depend on the elements of the input list, it always transforms the same way.. without looking at the implementation. The function `Ord a => [a] -> [a]` (`sort`) can transform depending on their ordering.

Comment: @Iceland_jack thats a very good point, thank you very much for explaining!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GHCi, you need to use the special commands `:{` and `:}` to enclose a multiline definition; otherwise, as pointed out in the comments, your second line just redefines the (partial) function you defined in the first line.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| product (x:xs) = x * product xs
Prelude| product [] = 1
Prelude| :}
Prelude>
```

Notice that after entering `:{`, the prompt switches from `>` to `|` to indicate that you are in the process of entering a multiline definition.

Alternatively, you can write your code in a `.hs` file, and `:load` it in GHCi. Doing so ensures that all the lines for a definition are considered.

Comment: Or write it in one line, the parts separated by semicolons